# Vscode source control stuck on publish branch

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Why is it that I am unable to push my code to github from vscode. When ever I make changes the source control menu only displays the publish branch button. I have been pushing code by opening the remote repo in a new vscode window and copy and pasting the code I wrote, then go into source control where I can commit.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyYtX.png)

Comment: Does  VScode show that you are on the correct branch (it is usually in the bottom left corner)?

Comment: @skyCode yep it is on the main branch

Comment: It is hard to pinpoint the exact issue based on the image, it might be something with your config. Did you try using the terminal inside VScode and typing "git status" to see if you get anything?

Comment: @skyCode i get this when using git status
https://imgur.com/a/6a0mQup

Comment: What might be a part of your issue is the warnings that you are getting about permission denied. Check this question and try to resolve this issue first, before trying to procide further.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614164/github-error-permission-denied-on-status